# How to add font color to content contained in json file?

Tags: css, json, styles

I would like to add css font style to sentence "Etappe 1 - reserviert" content to my .json file, e.g. font-color: blue; Can I do it the easiest way?

fragment Code .json file bottom

[
  {
    "title": "Haus 1",
    "url": "/haus/",
    "usable_area": 143.9,
    "land_area":

253.7,
    "garage": false,
    "shed": true,
    "price": "410 000",
    "status": "Etappe 1 - reserviert"
  },
  {
......
  }
]

Comment: i don't know if there's a plugin to do that, but if you are making http request to a server, you just get a piece of json like that... NOW in your app, yes you can change whatever you want when you render that strings

Comment: JSON is a data format, it makes rather little sense to ask about making something blue “in” that. This would be a matter of whatever application / script is _using_ that data and displaying it somehow - but you didn’t tell us anything about that part at all yet. If you just want to output the JSON as-is in string form in an HTML context, you could start with a simple search and replace approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the page, go below to the table that is in the json file. I marked on the screenshot. Is it possible to change the color of only one word that is in the json file?
http://sonnendomicil.at/

[Screen shot bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pIML.jpg)